# Time scale of Support Vector Classification in python

Tags: python, svm, grid-search

I am using a support vector machine, specifically scikit learn's svm.SVC with an rbf kernel to classify 28,000 images.

These images are of handwritten digits from 0 to 9, and my task is to classify what digit each image is. Each image is represented as a 28 X 28 matrix of pixels, so my data set is really a 3-D matrix of 28,000 X 28 X 28. So I flatten the 28 X 28 matrices to lists of 784 elements, which makes my data matrix now 28,000 X 784.

My strategy is to first find the best parameters for C and gamma. So I use a gridsearch with C in the range (10^0 to 10^4) and gamma in the range (10^-3 to 10^3). I then use k-fold with 10 folds and fit and score the svc with each possible combination of C and gamma on all 10 folds.

Here is my code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn import svm, cross_validation, grid_search
 import time

 digits = pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/Kaggle/Data/train_digits.csv")
 number_labels = digits['label'].values
 digits_pixels = digits.ix[:,'pixel0':]
 data = digits_pixels.values

 Classifier = svm.SVC()
 c_range = np.logspace(0,4,10)
 gamma_range = np.logspace(-3,3,10)
 K_folds = cross_validation.KFold(len(data),n_folds = 10)
 start_time = time.time()
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     Classifier_2 = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = Classifier, param_grid = dict(C = c_range, gamma = gamma_range), n_jobs = -1)
     scores =  [Classifier_2.fit(data[train],number_labels[train]).score(data[test],number_labels[test]) for train,test in K_folds]
 print "the program took",time.time() - start_time,"to run"
 print "mean score:" , np.mean(scores)
 print ("best C: %1.2f best gamma: %1.3f" %  (Classifier_2.best_estimator_.C,Classifier_2.best_estimator_.gamma))
```

The problem is that this code takes more than one hour to run through all the fitting and scoring, even though I am using multiprocessing with the gridsearch, with 40 cores. Is there any way that I can optimize the scoring and fitting? Or is there a huge mistake in the code which is slowing down the process? I know that when I score I am using the default scoring method of svm.svc, which I think is just a mean accuracy.